# laravel 4 upvote via ajax post

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I can't seem to get my voting system to work in ajax.  I'm trying to establish the 'upvote' and have my onclick function call my route and insert a vote accordingly, except nothing happens.  I can't see why or where I'm going wrong.

JAVASCRIPT

```
                    $( document ).ready(function() {
                        $(".vote").click(function() {

                            var id = $(this).attr("id");
                            var name = $(this).attr("name");
                            var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
                            var parent = $(this);

                        if (name=='up')
                        {

                            alert(dataString);
                            $(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="/img/vote-up-on.png" />');
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "http://domain.com/knowledgebase/upvote",
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: {id : id},
                                data: dataString,
                                cache: false,

                                success: function(html)
                                    {
                                    parent.html(html);
                                    }
                            });
                        }
                        if (name=='down')
                        {
                            alert(dataString);
                            $(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="/img/vote-down-on.png" />');
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "downvote",
                                data: dataString,
                                cache: false,

                                success: function(html)
                                    {
                                    parent.html(html);
                                    }
                            });
                        }
                        return false;
                        });
                    });
                    </script>
```

ROUTE.PHP

```
Route::get('knowledgebase/upvote/{id}', 'PostController@upvote');
```

POSTCONTROLLER.PHP

```
public function upvote($id)
{

    if (Auth::user()) {

        if (Request::ajax())  {

        $vote = "1";
        $user = Auth::user()->id;

        $post = Post::find($id);

        $checkvotes = Vote::where('post_id', $post->id)
            ->where('user_id', $user)
            ->first();

        if (empty($checkvotes))
                {
                    $entry = new Vote;
                    $entry->user_id = $user;
                    $entry->post_id = $post->id;
                    $entry->vote ="1";
                    $entry->save();

                }

        }

    }
    else
    {
        return "Not an AJAX request.";
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you checked the network section in your browser's developer tool for errors? Also check `app/storage/logs` folder for any errors that might have been logged.

Answer (score 0):

You are using post in your jquery, but you are waiting for a GET route.

Use...

```
Route::post('knowledgebase/upvote/{id}', 'PostController@upvote');
```

Additionally, the way you are handling your route may not work correctly with the id.  It would be expecting the id in the URL so what you can do is append your id to the url when setting up the ajax.

```
url: "http://domain.com/knowledgebase/upvote/"+id,
```

Or not use it at all, take the {id} portion out of your route, and grab it using `Input::get('id');`

Comment: I tried both these methods and neither work I'm afraid.

Comment: @user3189734 what does the console tells you? What's the error and what's its content?